# BigQuery StandardSQL returns 2022-52 as year-isoweek for 2022-01-01

Tags: date, google-bigquery

In BigQuery StandardSQL, format_date("%Y-%V",DATE "2022-01-01") returns 2022-52 while it should actually be 2021-52. Does anyone know how to fix this/ how to get the correct year for the respective ISO-WEEK?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after:

```
select EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM DATE "2022-01-01") as theisoyear,
       EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE "2022-01-01") AS theisoweek;
```

Answer (score 2):

With **%G** for ISO year instead of **%Y**,

```sql
select format_date("%G-%V",DATE "2022-01-01")
```

you can get **2021-51**.